# What is the returned value of PackangeManager.getInstallerPackageName for Sony Bravia TV default store

Tags: java, sony, android-tv, television

I need to distinguish if my application (running on the same Sony Bravia TV) was installed from the Sony app store or from the Google one. Looking for a way to do that [PackangeManager.getInstallerPackageName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String)) come in handy but I would like to know what value can I expect for the Sony default store. Is it going to be null or does Sony populate with some value - like "com.android.vending" for Google and "com.amazon.venezia" for Amazon (from what I was able to find).

Answer (score 0):

For Sony Android TV all apps are distributed via Google Play store. There are no Sony app store. The featured apps row and Sony Select are just links into Google Play Store.

Comment: Thank you very much Tonni. In that case is there a way to differentiate an application launch from the Sony Select / featured app from all the other potential locations?

Comment: To get on the featured apps row and Sony Select requires a contract with Sony. So if you don't have that, the app will always be launched from the normal app row where the location/order can be customized by the user.

Comment: I believe that is the case. Our client do has a contract and we are suppose to provide a slightly different, Sony-specific behavior within  the application when it is launched from that location. I am now evaluating if this is technically possible.